# WEB API .NET 5 Stream JSON objects to the client fetch request

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

With the following source code I am able to stream JSON objects via ASP.NET Web API, that's fine & cool !
I would like to migrate this source code to .NET 5. Since PushStreamContent class is not provided any more, Can anyone help me to facing with solution ? Any reference or examples are kindly accepted.
Mersi

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMultipartData()
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            var content = new PushStreamContent(new Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext>(WriteContent), "application/json");

            response.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
            response.Content = content;

            return response;
        }

        public static void WriteContent(Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
            
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jw.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var id in Enumerable.Range(1, 100000))
                { 
                    serializer.Serialize(jw, new TestModel()
                    {
                        Alias = "rvhuang",
                        BirthDate = new DateTime(1985, 02, 13),
                        FirstName = "Robert",
                        LastName = "Huang",
                        ID = id,
                        MiddleName = "Vandenberg",
                    });
                }
                jw.WriteEndArray();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string FirstName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string MiddleName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public DateTime BirthDate
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Alias
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public int ID
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should be using SSE to stream JSON to a client instead of chunked transfer encoding: it scales better and supports reconnections. It's built-in to SignalR.

Comment: Dai, SSE is used more to send notification data to client, isn't it ?

Comment: SSE is unidirectional, yes.

Comment: With the class PushStreamContent I'am also able to send back to the client an array of objects one by one and display a progress bar for each element I'am receiving. My pourpose his to understand how can realize it in .NET 5. I will provide some example to you in github as I will able to do it.

Comment: Dear, I have set up a project with .net 4.8 framework here: github.com/lluthus/asp-net-web-api.git. I would like to create the same solution taking advantage of the new .NET 5 framework.

Comment: .NET 5 (not ".NET 5 Framework") is **completely incompatible** with .NET Framework 4.8. What you're asking simply isn't possible.